# How to fix: Ubuntu 12.04 reboots after loading with elilo

Tags: 12.04, installation, reboot, uefi

I have an HP p6-2120 with

```
 CPU: AMD A6-3620 APU with Radeon Graphics
  RAM: 6GB
  BIOS: HO2_710.ROM v7.10 [AMI v7.10 4/19/2012]
  Disk: SATA1 (/dev/sda) - 1 TB (windows)
  Disk: SATA2 (/dev/sdb) - 1 TB partitioned using "parted -a optimal /dev/sdb" as follows:
..    1049KB 201MB FAT32 boot flag set
..    201MB 60GB ext2 (/)
..    68GB 78GB linux-swap(v1) (swap)
..    78GB 790GB ext4 (/home)
..    - rest is "free" space reserved for other purposes (eventually)

  ubuntu: 12.04.1 LTS [specifically: Release 12.04 (precise) 64-bit]
  kernel: linux 3.2.0-29-generic
```

I created a bootable EFI USB from the ISO (64-bit) which I downloaded. I can run and install from the USB without any problems.

The BIOS is an EFI bios that appears to be capable of booting in either EFI or Legacy mode. 
Initially, I did the "standard" install with NOTHING on disk2, and let the installer configure everything. The net result of this was that when I started the computer and forced it into "boot" menu mode, it DOES NOT recognize SATA2 as an EFI drive, and when I attempt to "legacy" boot from it, I get the message "ERROR: No Boot Disk has been detected." The "standard" install created one large partition that consumed the entire disk.

At that point, I manually partitioned the disk (using sudo parted -a optimal /dev/sdb) as described above. I selected the "other" install, and changed the /dev/sdb1 to "bios_grub", /dev/sdb2 as "/" (ext4), /dev/sdb3 as swap, and /dev/sdb4 as "/home". [Note: fearing that possibly elilo did not recognize ext4, I switched /dev/sdb2 to ext2 and re-insalled]

The net result was that the install appeared to trash the /dev/sdb1 partition so that it was NOT readable by anything.

I re-formated /dev/sdb1 as FAT32 and set the boot flag. I repeated the install ignoring the messages about no bios_grub partition.

After several attempts to get GRUB2 to work, I switched to elilo. I downloaded the most recent version and copied it (elilo-3.14-ia64.efi) to /dev/sdb1/efi/boot/bootx64.efi. (The BIOS boot loader did not recognize it either as elilo-3.14.ia64.efi or as elilo.efi. Based on the advice in one of the web-pages I found, I renamed it to bootx64.efi. This worked.)

In that same directory (/efi/boot), I copied the file pointed to the link in /dev/sdb2/vmlinuz to /efi/boot/vmlinuz, and the file pointed to the link in /dev/sdb2/initrd.img to /efi/boot/initrd.img. I created an elilo.conf file as follows:

```
timeout=5000
prompt
default=linux-boot
image=vmlinuz
  label=linux-boot
  read-only
  initrd=initrd.img
  root=/dev/sdb2

The /efi/boot directory contains 4 files:
bootx64.efi
elilo.conf
vmlinuz
initrd.img
```

When I power-cycle the computer and force the boot menu, drive2 shows up as an EFI bootable drive. When I select it, I get the elilo prompt. Pressing , it appears to load the kernal (I have tried it with verbose=5, and there is a long string of messages with the final one a command line to load the kernel and a series of several dots that fly by) then the screen goes blank, and it reboots the computer. [Note: I have also tried substituting the UUID as found in the /etc/fstab of the installed system for the root directory. This had no effect.]

This is a brief synopsis of several nights of fiddling with this. I would deeply appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: Please could you indicate your [Boot-Info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) URL?

Answer (score 1):

I have been asking everyone I know what the problem may be

A friend - a sys admin - pointed out that even though I have been booting the install from an EFI disk, the ubuntu installer does not appear to have detected that and wants to install as a Legacy style device.

He suggested re-initializing the disk to MBR (rather than GPT), and trying the install that way.

I reinitialized /dev/sdb as an MBR disk
I booted the install disk with and EFI loader and did a standard install (keep windows, install Ubuntu, nothing special). It installed and worked fine!

Conclusion: Even if you have an EFI system, if the Ubuntu installer wants to install in Legacy mode, oblige it!

Comment: FYI: instead of formatting everything, you could have simply created an EFI partition via Gparted, then convert your Ubuntu install into EFI mode via the `Separate /boot/efi` option of [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).